# Is there a "task list" form MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

Is there an equivalent of the Visual Studio Task List in MS Access?

I'd love to by able to put TODO's in my code and see what I have open at a glance.

Comment: You can always have a "todo.txt" in the same directory, open in notepad :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have fun :)

```
Sub ToDoList()
Dim afind As Variant
Dim sfound as String
Dim mdl As Object
Dim modtext As String, modarray As Variant
Dim leline As Long
Dim i, j, k   

afind = Split("HACK,TODO", ",")

For i = 1 To VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count
    Set mdl = VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents(i).CodeModule
    leline = mdl.CountOfLines
    If leline > 0 Then
        modtext = mdl.Lines(1, leline)           
        For j = 0 To UBound(afind)
            If InStr(modtext, afind(j)) > 0 Then
                sfound = sfound & vbCrLf & "****" & afind(j) _
                       & " found in " & mdl.Name
                modarray = Split(modtext, vbCrLf)
                For k = 0 To UBound(modarray)
                    If InStr(modarray(k), afind(j)) > 0 Then
                        sfound = sfound & vbCrLf & k
                        sfound = sfound & "  " & modarray(k)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

MsgBox sfound
End Sub
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I used it to build my own Task List window. Thanks +1

Comment: The only real change was I created a "utility" form I can copy into any of my mdb's and outputs the results into a large text box rather than as a MsgBox as Remou used. (and I defined "sfound" as a string :-) )

Comment: The original version searched all mdbs in a directory.